# How does shuffle = 'batch' argument of the .fit() layer work in the background?

Tags: keras, shuffle, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

When I train the model using the `.fit()` layer there is the argument shuffle preset to True.

Let's say that my dataset has 100 samples and that the batch size is 10. When I set `shuffle = True` then keras first randomly selects randomly the samples (now the 100 samples have a different order) and on the new order it will start creating the batches: batch 1: 1-10, batch 2: 11-20 etc.

If I set `shuffle = 'batch'` how is it supposed to work in the background? Intuitively and using the previous example of 100 samples dataset with batch size = 10 my guess would be that keras first allocates the samples to the batches (i.e. batch 1: samples 1-10 following the dataset original order, batch 2: 11-20 following the dataset original order as well, batch 3 ... so on so forth) and then shuffles the order of the batches. So the model now will be trained on the randomly ordered batches say for example: 3 (contains samples 21 - 30), 4 (contains samples 31 - 40), 7 (contains samples 61 - 70), 1 (contains samples 1 - 10), ... (I made up the order of the batches).

Is my thinking right or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the implementation at this [link](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/3f148e40e1dd9b95c4cd2dd0d182b8729729a5c0/keras/engine/training.py#L349) (line 349 of training.py) the answer seems to be positive.

Try this code for checking:

```
import numpy as np
def batch_shuffle(index_array, batch_size):
    """Shuffles an array in a batch-wise fashion.
    Useful for shuffling HDF5 arrays
    (where one cannot access arbitrary indices).
    # Arguments
        index_array: array of indices to be shuffled.
        batch_size: integer.
    # Returns
        The `index_array` array, shuffled in a batch-wise fashion.
    """
    batch_count = int(len(index_array) / batch_size)
    # to reshape we need to be cleanly divisible by batch size
    # we stash extra items and reappend them after shuffling
    last_batch = index_array[batch_count * batch_size:]
    index_array = index_array[:batch_count * batch_size]
    index_array = index_array.reshape((batch_count, batch_size))
    np.random.shuffle(index_array)
    index_array = index_array.flatten()
    return np.append(index_array, last_batch)


x = np.array(range(100))
x_s = batch_shuffle(x,10)
```