# Keras curriculum learning- change shuffle method

Tags: keras, deep-learning, shuffle

I want to change the way we shuffle training data in Keras. Conventionally we shuffle samples in each epoch and then we batch, and fit the model. Now I want to first batch the samples, and then shuffle these "BATCHES" (all samples in each batch should not shuffle). The reason is that I ordered all samples based on criteria (Curriculum Learning) and I want to preserve such an order.
Do you know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer according to this link:
[How does shuffle = 'batch' argument of the .fit() layer work in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567692/how-does-shuffle-batch-argument-of-the-fit-layer-work-in-the-background)

Short answer: we need to set shuffle='batch' in fit.